# SQL Server FOR XML PATH ROOT element with attribute (Path Mode symbol @ or / )

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml-path, for-xml

I need output something like this

```
<Employee EmpID="4">
  <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>
  <LastName>Walters</LastName>
</Employee>
<Employee EmpID="168">
  <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>T</MiddleName>
  <LastName>Caron</LastName>
</Employee>
```

But the SQL to do this:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID AS "@EmpID",
   c.FirstName, 
   c.MiddleName, c.LastName
FROM Employee AS e 
INNER JOIN Contact AS c 
ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Ross'
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('Employees');
```

Return this error:

```
SQL Server Database Error: Row tag omission (empty row tag name) cannot be used with attribute-centric FOR XML serialization.
```

See the SQLFiddle:

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a1597)

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT e.EmployeeID AS "@EmpID" FOR XML PATH ('EmployeeID'), TYPE), c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName ... FOR XML PATH ('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees');` is probably what you're after.

Comment: Hey @ZLK
Thanks, but is not that... the result from your code was: 
`<Employee><Employee EmpID="256"/><FirstName>Ross</FirstName><MiddleName></MiddleName><LastName>Geller</LastName></Employee>` 
[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a159/3/0) 

but i need 

`<Employee EmpID="256"><FirstName>Ross</FirstName><MiddleName></MiddleName><LastName>Geller</LastName></Employee>`

Comment: Uh, then all you should need to do is change `for xml path ('')` to `for xml path ('Employee')` in your current query.

Comment: For reference: [Link: "Red Gate - Using the FOR XML Clause"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/)

Comment: @ZLK 
This work well, thanks.... [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a159/8/0)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do is using the right code:

```
SELECT 
e.EmployeeID AS "@EmpID",
c.FirstName, 
c.MiddleName, c.LastName
FROM Employee AS e 
INNER JOIN Contact AS c 
ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Ross'
FOR XML PATH ('Employee')
;
```

Like the right SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a159/8/0